# Manually delete ConflictAndDeleted

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs, dfs-r, file-replication-services

we're looking to reclaim space on our DCs and have found that the ConflictAndDeleted folder is huge in System Volume Information > DFSR > Private.

There is one folder in particular which is the cause of the size which has 600GB worth of disk images that used to be stored, I've checked the .xml file and it references a Replication Group that we no longer have being replicated, which was removed a while ago. The source folder was deleted along with the replication group, however the files are still in ConflictAndDeleted.

How do we reclaim this space safely, is it safe to manually delete through explorer? I don't have much experience with DFS so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks